Oozie workflow arguments interprets double quotes weirdly for spark-submit command parameters
I have a Spark job which takes a bunch of configurable parameters. I am facing an issue specifically in this portion:
--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=&quot;-Duser.timezone=PST -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35&quot; 

For some reason, Oozie interprets this as:
--conf 'spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-Duser.timezone=PST' -XX:+UseG1GC '-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35"' 

instead of:
--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-Duser.timezone=PST -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35"

I have tried various combinations, but most of them give wrong results. Used <![CDATA[--conf ...]]> as well but to no avail. Any help appreciated
